# Finding the right model

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

Let us say that i have two ball throwing machines which has some algorithm running in the back-end for releasing the balls. One machine shows it throws 5 balls in 1 sec. Other shows the exact distribution of how many balls were thrown in each 0.2 secs (say the distribution is: 2,1,0,1,1) but the sum is 5 balls/sec for this machine too. Can i use this data and some other independent parameters like speed, direction etc as inputs and predict the similar distribution for lower accuracy machine.?

Re-framing my question:

I am searching for an apt supervised model for the following use case:

If I have a  sum (say 10) and it can be distributed in a predefined number of bins (say 5) in a number of ways for instance:

**1.** 1, 2, 5, 0, 2

**2.** 0, 0, 3, 7, 0

etc.

The distribution bins always have whole numbers and the sum is also a whole number. The distribution depends on a number of factors and patterns which can be learned in the volumetric data. Hence, if I am able to load more than one sum (say n sums) and output the corresponding n*5 distributions it will be better for precise prediction (as per my intuitions). I tried using some networks but they are not doing much good.